# Cross-platform Executable Questions (avoiding duplicate)

Tags: java, executable, executable-jar

I know that windows users prefer **.exe** (Windows **EXE**cutables) and mac users prefer **.app** (AppleScript **app**lication) and Java uses **.jar** (**J**ava **AR**chive). But is there any reasonable cross-platform executable because to execute JAR you need the CMD or Terminal (at least in the case of a Mac) to run the file by using:

```
java -jar %FILEPATH%
```

But is there any other executable I can use?

Should I just have a Mac and a Windows downloads?

Can I make a jar that can be double clicked?

I have searched as far as I can in stock overflow but no simple reasonable answer.

Hope this can help more people than me :)

Comment: Could you please explain what "avoiding duplicate" means in relation to executable files?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there are a lot of other questions 'like' this one but all the answers are either .jar, .app or .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to start a jar file via double-click, the .jar extension needs to be associated with the Java Runtime executable, `javaw.exe` under Windows. That is the same mechanism used to open for example `.docx` files with Microsoft Word.
As far as I know, the JRE installation adds such an association automatically.

In order to tell Java which class to start from the Jar after it was double-clicked, you need a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in the Jar, like @Elliott Frisch described.

By the way: Mac apps are in fact folders, which Mac OS X shows as one piece (right-click on a Mac app and click `Show Package Contents` to enter that folder). So the idea is very similar to Jars, although Jars are real files and not folder -- and of course their format is totally different.

So a Jar is the format "executable" on all platforms (having a JRE installed).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this right now! I have been adding manifest files but I had no idea it had be in a folder named META-INF!  I know how the mac applications work, I have worked with them before with the built in AppleScript editor.

Answer (score 0):

An executable JAR file is the most portable cross-platform *executable*. Macintosh app files are [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format, and not compatible with [Windows Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). The Windows executable format is not compatible with Mac or Linux ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)). Basically, the only format that will reliably run on Windows, Mac and Linux is a Jar File.

From [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) the Java Tutorials,

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the `Main-Class` header in the manifest, which has the general form:
>
> ```
> Main-Class: classname
> ```

Comment: Thanks I have used manifests before and even tried this but no luck.

Comment: Thanks i have finally got mine working thanks to your help i am now working on swing!